# How to make a click function in javascript loop through all records instead of just the first record

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a feeling this problem I've having trouble with is pretty simple but I am new to all this and don't know all the ins and outs of html, javascript, etc. yet. The javascript functions is what's really difficult to learn for me. Anyways, I have an item cart where the users add whatever products they want to order. I'm trying to implement a function where when the user clicks the "Proceed To Checkout" button it checks to make sure whatever qty they are ordering does not exceed the amount we have in stock. If it does then display an alert message. I have a function working perfectly at the moment, but it is only checking the first record and not looping through anything. Any thoughts or insight on what I can do would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
   @foreach (var item in (List<Item>)Session["cart"])
    {
        <tr>
          <td>
            @item.Pr.Product_Code
          </td>
          <td>
            @item.Pr.Description<br />
            <span class="text-left" id="errmsg"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="~/Images/@item.Pr.ImageUrl" width="100" height="80" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" value="@item.Qty" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="amtOrdered" /><br />
            <input type="text" value="@item.Pr.Qty_Available" id="qty-avbl" name="qty-avbl" class="amt-avbl" hidden />
          </td>
          <td class="btn-sctn">
            <button class="button">
               <i class="fa solid fa-trash-o"></i>
               @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", "ItemCart", new { id = item.Pr.ProductID },
                           new { onclick = "return confirm ('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');", @class = "remove" })
            </button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      }
    </table>
         <div></div>
         <hr />
         <p class="place-order">
            <input type="submit" class="checkout" value="Proceed To Checkout" id="checkQty" />
         </p>
         <p class="keep-shop">
            @Html.ActionLink("Continue Shopping", "ProductCatalog", "Products", "", new { @class = "shopping-link" })
         </p>
      }@*End of form*@
    }@*End of if session*@
```

and my function I have for this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#checkQty").click(function (event) {
            // Get the value of the input field with id
            let qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            let avbl = document.getElementById("qty-avbl").value;
            let text;
                if (qty > avbl) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    text = "There is not enough stock to order this amount";
                    document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = text;
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    text = "";
                }           
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried instead of getting the element by id, use the `getelementsbyclassname` inside a for loop?, while ids are unique, multiple elements can share the same class

Comment: @ChrisG, I have tried the getElementsByClassName and it wasn't working, I had to switch back to getting it by id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope it will solve your problem based on what you described.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkQty").click(function (event) {
        // Get the value of the input field with id
        let qtys = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="quantity"]');
        let avbls = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="qty-avbl"]');
        let text;
        
        // assumming the quantity and available quantity inputs will be adjacent and equal in number
        for(let i=0; i < qtys.length; i++){
            let qty = qtys[i].value;
            let avbl = avbls[i].value;

            if (qty > avbl) {
                event.preventDefault();
                text = "There is not enough stock to order this amount";
                document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = text;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                text = "";
            }     
        }
  
    });
});
```

Here you can use **for-of** or **foreach** loop as well to iterate over all the inputs.

Comment: Thank you Ali for the response! I tried it out and it appears to be working correctly by looping through and checking each qty but the error message "errmsg" is only displaying in the first record. So let's say there's 5 products in the cart, if the 3rd item is the one that triggers the alert, the alert message still displays in the first record. Any clue how I can get it to show for any record that gets triggered?

Comment: Do the same with "errmsg" that we did with quantity and available quantity inputs. i.e. give it a name say "errormsg" and reference it by **let errorMsgs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="errormsg"]');**. Then in if condition set its innerHtml like **errorMsgs[i].innerHTML = text;**

Comment: the error message is not an input though, its just in a span element. Can I still reference it in the queryselectorall bracket without using "input"?

Comment: Oh my bad, it will be **let errorMsgs = document.querySelectorAll('[name="errormsg"]');**

Comment: You can also give it class name "errormsg" and use **let errorMsgs = document.querySelectorAll('.errormsg');** instead as well.

Comment: that did seem to fix it, except it's only doing the first triggered qty instead of before when it was doing just the first record. Atleast it has the correct record where it's displaying the error message but I still gotta figure out how to get it to display for all the records. Do I need to add anything under the "let avbl = avbls[i].value;" line?

Comment: Ali, this is working perfect now, thank you so much for helping me figure it out! I'm still pretty new to this and these javascript functions are tough. Anyways, I took out the "return false" part and it fixed it where appears for all the records that trigger the error message! thank you!